# Set EnableSendfile Off from Dockerfile

Tags: apache, docker

Hi I'm trying to understand how to add configuration commands in Dockerfile but so far I don't get any good results.
I wrote this line

```
RUN sed -i 'EnableSendfile Off' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

how would be the correct version?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am wondering if the sed command works as your wrote it down.

```
RUN sed -i -e 's/this/that/g' filename
```

works fine, so it could be

```
RUN sed -i -e 's/EnableSendfile On/EnableSendfile Off/g' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

What kind of results or errors do you have?

Comment: Thanks it worked like that the error was that wasn't expecting the character E after the quote